# Which custom HTTP header names worth to use?

Tags: node.js, http, openshift

I see that if using custom HTTP header names, some of them will received by server i.e. `filename`, `operation`, but some like `databaseName` is not received. Any idea why? Should I use  `filename`, `operation` at all?

Using `OpenShift` platform with preconfigured `Node.js` web server.

Comment: If you're sending an HTTP request with those headers, and they don't end up in your server, you have two possible problems: a noncompilant or malconfigured firewall, or a crappy HTTP server. We can't answer this without any information about what your setup and tests look like. You may want to read [ask] and include enough details into your question so that others can understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the case than not all HTTP headers are received by the server. Try this example:

```
var app = require('express')();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.end('header is ' + req.get('databaseName') + '\n');
});

app.listen(3333, () => console.log('listening on 3333'));
```

Start it with `node app.js` (or whatever you saved it as) and connect with :

```
curl http://localhost:3333
```

You will get:

```
header is undefined
```

But when you send the header:

```
curl http://localhost:3333 -H 'databaseName: ABC'
```

You will get:

```
header is ABC
```

So certainly the server gets the header.

You may experience issues with your client code not sending the header in question, or with a misconfigured proxy removing certain headers. But this is not the case that certain headers are not received by the server as you can see by running my example.

Answering your question "Which custom HTTP header names worth to use?" is really up to you. Every header that you need is worth using. Every header that you don't need is not worth using.

Also note that the `X-` prefix for custom headers used to be a widely used convention. It has been deprecated by [RFC 6648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648) but you may still have some more luck with using `X-DatabaseName` instead of `DatabaseName` header names to avoid some collisions.